# Find row ID using InnoDB page ID

Tags: mysql, innodb

Is there a way to find the table row(record) ID using the InnoDB page ID.

Reason:
I recently had a database crash, the logs mention a corrupt page and supply a page ID. Right now I am analyzing the cause of the crash whether  it be a 1. corruption on disk, 2. failed read, 3. corrupt index or 4. corrupt OS file cache.

I would like to try and trigger the issue and see if it is persistent but, for that I need to know the row ID and all I have is the InnoDB page ID.

Comment: [**SOLVED**] The error log also contains an ASCII dump of the corrupt page, thus including the IDs. This now enables me to attempt to trigger the issue which will assist me in my troubleshooting.

Comment: It is perfectly acceptable if you answer your own question and then mark that answer as accepted. That way other people will immediately see that the problem is resolved